# Better way to advance DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a more efficient way to advance a date to just after now keeping the same hour? The code below advances a day at a time but I wonder if there's a more efficient way to achieve the same result.

```
var now = DateTime.Parse("27/03/2018 02:35");
var startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2000 16:00");

while (startDate < now)
{
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}

Console.WriteLine(startDate);  // 27/03/2018 16:00:00
```

Comment: `advance a date to just after now keeping the same hour?` what, exactly, is that supposed to mean? And in short, `AddDays`, `AddMinutes`, `AddHours`, etc are about as simple as you are going to get.

Comment: you could subtract the start and end dates and compute how many days you need to advance, rather than looping (maybe 5000 times, ??)

Comment: By "keeping the same hour" do you actually mean "keeping the same time of day"? Are you actually just looking for `now.Date + startDate.TimeOfDay` perhaps? That won't do quite the same thing as your loop if `startDate` has an earlier time-of-day than `now`... it would really help if you'd explain what you're trying to achieve more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need

```
var now = DateTime.Parse("27/03/2018 12:00");
var startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2000 16:00");
var adjustedDate = now.Date.Add(startDate.TimeOfDay);
var finalDate = DateTime.Compare(now, adjustedDate) >= 0 ? 
adjustedDate.AddDays(1) : adjustedDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why you can't take the date portion from one and the time portion from another?

```
    var now = DateTime.Parse("03/27/2018 02:35");
    var startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2000 16:00");
    var result = now.Date.Add(startDate.TimeOfDay);

    Console.WriteLine(result);  // 03/27/2018 16:00:00
```

Comment: That's what I've suggested in comments too, but it doesn't behave the same way as the current code, if the time-of-day of `startDate` is earlier than the time-of-day of `now`. That's why I've asked for clarification.

Comment: The time should remain the same (startDate), and become the next date after now.

Comment: If now was 27/03/2018 16:35 the result should be 28/03/2018 16:00